# How to correctly call fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, writefile

I can't figure out how to write on a JSON file.
I'm working on a Single Application Page, using mostly AngularJS and Node.js

This is my code:

--index.html--

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="pages/Animazione.html">
    ...
    <td><input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" ng-click="doPost()" /></td>
```

--app.js--

```
var App = angular.module('myMovie', ['ngRoute']);
...
.when('/Animazione', {
        templateUrl : 'pages/Animazione.html',
        controller  : 'AnimazioneController'}
     )
...
App.controller('AnimazioneController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

                    $http.get('Animazione.json').success(function(response)
                    {
                        $scope.myData=response;
                    })
                    .error(function()
                    { 
                        alert("Si è verificato un errore!"); 
                    });


                    $scope.doPost = function()
                {
                    writeOutputFile({test: 1});
                };


}]);
```

--index.js-- (Server)

```
function writeOutputFile(data, success, fail) {
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile('auth.json', JSON.stringify(data), function(error) {
    if(error) { 
      console.log('[write output]: ' + err);
        if (fail)
          fail(error);
    } else {
      console.log('[write output]: success');
        if (success)
          success();
    }
  });
}
```

Is there any call or any function that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't call a function directly which in the server via client.

To do this, define and end point in the server and from client make a call to that end point. Inside the handler for that end point in server call your function to write to file.

Eg: In server define `/writefile` endpoint like below (where express is used in server side) Add below contents to `index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var cors = require('cors');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());

app.post('/writefile', function(req, res) {
    var fileData = req.body.fileContent;
    fs.writeFile('message.txt', fileData , function(err) {
      if (err) {
         res.status(500).jsonp({ error: 'Failed to write file' });
      }
      res.send("File write success");
    });
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

var port = 3000;

app.set('port', port);
var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

Now your server is running in 3000 port.

In client:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost:3000/writefile', // Assuming your running your node server in local
   data: { "fileContent": {"test": 1} } // Content which needs to be written to the file 'message.txt'
}).then(function(){
   // Success
}, 
function(error) {
   //error handler
   console.error("Error occured::",error);
});
```

Comment: Could you explain me where app.post comes from and what to write excactly in url: and data: ?

Comment: @N.Cozzolino Updated the answer for the app.post and url and data. Please give a try and let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: Thanks, anyway I have two errors now (checking with Console Debugger on Chrome):

-var express = require('express'); "require is not defined"

-http://localhost:300/writefile "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Comment: @N.Cozzolino It is working file for me. I have tested. Can you share your node js version. 'require' must be available out-of-the-box with nodejs. Also the localhost:300/writefile is a post request, use poster to test it

Comment: I'm using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044, do you recommend me to use Eclipse? Node.js version is: v0.10.13_x86

Comment: @N.Cozzolino your node js version is very old. Can you upgrade it and try. Also to test it quickly you can install all the dependent package(whichever is required in index.js) and run by calling `node index.js`

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/ecwcO)
That's the error I get, I updated Node.js.

Comment: @N.Cozzolino Add these dependencies in `dependencies` section of  `package.json` of your project `"body-parser": "~1.15.1", "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3", "cors": "^2.8.1", "express": "~4.13.4"`. Then call `npm install`, once all packages are installed start the server by `node index.js`

For reference below is the `package.json` contents : 
`{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "express": "~4.13.4"
  }
}`

Comment: There are no errors now, thanks!
Anyway is it correct "url: 'http://localhost:300/writefile'," (in client)
and "var port = 3000;" in the server?

Comment: @N.Cozzolino It is 3000 in both the places. It was a typo. I have corrected and updated the answer. `"url": "http://localhost:3000/writefile"`

Comment: I'm so close to the solution, sorry to bother you again. Now this is my client code: [link](http://imgur.com/a/2qz54) and every time I get the Error! alert (even if now the index.js server is all settled and working).
I'm using Aptana and using FireFox i get this address: [link](http://imgur.com/a/3jPGb)

Comment: Can you share me the error in browser console or capture the error objects in error handler and log it. See the updated answer above for capturing error

Comment: Can try one thing, using any poster client make a post request to localhost:3000/writefile and see where the data is written. [link](http://imgur.com/a/Aeyo8) for the sample post request. I am using **Advanced REST Client Chrome Extension**

Comment: Can you share the full screen shot... So that I can see the URL. Also share me the screenshot of your node server running. I mean output of `node index.js`

Comment: Advanced REST: [link](http://imgur.com/a/xzNT7)
Node.js: [link](http://imgur.com/a/CVeKC)

Comment: The logic is working perfectly fine for me: [Screenshots link](https://postimg.org/gallery/1tarx2hu8/). Also try access `http://localhost:3000` in browser and see are you getting the similar error as shown in screen shot `error`

Comment: Ok, so now with **Advanced REST Client Chrome Extension** everything works (while running the node index.js). I get same error as you if I access to http://localhost:3000.
Now when I launch my application there's no creation of any file (but procedure it's ok as I get the alert "OK!"), I also checked console debugger with Chrome but no errors, only no file created.

Comment: Hmm. It should create a file. Do one think copy only `package.json` and `index.js` into a separate directory. And run `npm install` and after that `node index.js`. Then file the request using **Advanced REST Client**. Let see whether it create a file or not ?

Comment: Ok, there's some news. With the steps that you indicated me, is everything ok. Instead in my app I can only create a file named "message.txt" (any other name won't create the file), with this output: [link](http://imgur.com/a/05vX7)

Comment: That's great!... So try with the same name in your app. And Do accept the answer as well :)